# How to get FileId or OwnerId or CustomAttribut in Qbwc file in wsdl implementation

Tags: quickbooks, qbwc

I am thinking of how I can fetch fileId or ownerId or any custom attribute in any or all wsdl methods. I am thinking to create generic qbwc file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
 <AppName>WCWebService1</AppName>
 <AppID></AppID>
 <AppURL>http://localhost:8000/wsdl </AppURL>
 <AppDescription>A short description for WCWebService1</AppDescription>
 <AppSupport>http://developer.intuit.com</AppSupport>
 <UserName>Admin</UserName>
 <OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D20}</OwnerID>
 <FileID>{90A 44FB5-33D9-4815-AC85-BC87A7E7D1EB}</FileID>
 <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
 <Scheduler>
 <RunEveryNMinutes>2</RunEveryNMinutes>
 </Scheduler>
</QBWCXML>
```

Not sure how to get those attribute. Was able to get ticketid in all of them but that is random uuid creating after auth.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/companyquery

You can add OwnerID to the Company Query and you should receive it on the DataExtRet key on the response

```
<CompanyQueryRq>
        <IncludeRetElement >STRTYPE</IncludeRetElement> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
        <OwnerID >GUIDTYPE</OwnerID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
</CompanyQueryRq>
```

In my case, I opted to use a JWT for the password so I'm using that to identify the user and issue a session JWT (sent as ticket)